# Heap corruption at program termination

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic, heap-corruption

I can't figure out what is causing this memory leak (I assume that's what's going on.)

I've got several classes, so I'll post the constructors and destructors of each. The error message says the corruption is caused by the memory allocated at stock.cpp(20) which is the line

```
symbol(new char[]),
```

The constructors and destructors are as follows

hashmap.cpp

```
HashMap::HashMap(int capacity) :
  slots(new Slot[capacity]), 
  capacity(capacity), 
  nStocks(0),
  isEmpty(true)

HashMap::~HashMap(void)
{
    delete[] slots;
}
```

stock.cpp

```
Stock::Stock(char const * const symbol, char const * const name, int sharePrice, Date priceDate):
  symbol(new char[strlen(symbol)+1]),
  name(new char[strlen(name) + 1]),
  sharePrice(sharePrice),
  priceDate(priceDate),
  isEmpty(false)
{
  strcpy(this->symbol, symbol);
  strcpy(this->name, name);
}

Stock::Stock(void) :
  symbol(new char[]),  //this is where the memory allocation that causes the error occurs
  name(new char[]),
  isEmpty(true)

Stock::~Stock(void)
{
  delete[] symbol;
  delete[] name;
}
```

As you can see, the array that is allocated at stock.cpp(20) is destroyed when the destructor is called. So what's going on?

EDIT: Here is the complete error message

Debug Error!

Program: asnmt03/Debug/asnmt03.ext

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#168) at 0x004E51F8
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

Memory allocated at stock.cpp(20)

Comment: Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: @reirab Edited it in to the OP

Comment: You have been writing outside an array's bounds.

Comment: You cannot write `new char[]`. You should supply a default size.

Comment: timrau's right, but even with that fix you're not safe if you let the `Stock` objects be copied - which the `HashMap` might do occasionally (google "Rule of Three").  More generally - why aren't you using `std::string`?  You'd avoid lost time on issues like this.

Comment: @TonyD my school has an obsession with only using dynamically allocated c-strings

Comment: Well, they're probably trying to force you to learn to manage them properly... do learn the Rule of Three carefully.  Cheers.